# How to directly save HTML/CSS animations to a video file (AVI)?

Tags: html, css, video, css-transitions, css-animations

Without a screen recorder, Is it possible to directly export, render, or save HTML CSS animations to a video file? I'm also aware SVG within a html document could also be a part of such a process.

I tried searching online for a solution, but I only get "Export After Effects to CSS...". Seems like there's no answer. Surely if your browser can render it, there must be some code that'll be able to export it..?

Ideally, id write some `div`s and some css animation code, see how it looks on Chrome, then maybe click a button and export little clips of what the browser rendered. Could be an extension, or anything.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the above scenario ?

Comment: Similar question with some answers: https://superuser.com/questions/434649/how-to-take-a-css-animation-from-a-browser-and-export-a-gif-of-it

Answer (score 0):

There's a good extension where you can create a screencasting from a website and export it to AVI, on https://screencast-o-matic.com/tutorial/save-as-a-video-file

The thing is that you won't be able to achieve that without recording your screen.

I'm assuming you can copy the code and pass it to an expert in video edition and they will create an emulation from the animation you want, they may do it in Adobe After Effects or a different video software, but that's like the expensive solution.

Fiverr might have some freelancers that can do that.